# Birkhoff decomposition with maximization objective.

Tags: matrices, optimization, permutation-matrices, stochastic-matrices, birkhoff-polytopes

Given a [doubly-stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix) matrix $\pi$, Birkhoff-von Neumann theorem states that $\pi$ can be written as a convex combination of [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix):

$$\pi=\sum_{i\leq k} \alpha_i B_i$$

where $\sum_{i \leq k} \alpha_i$ = 1 and $B_i$ are the permutation matrices. Such decomposition is generally not unique. I am looking for an algorithm that finds a particular decomposition that maximizes some objective. For example, suppose that for each $i$ there is a scalar $r_i$. I wish to find a decomposition s.t. $\sum_{i\leq k} \alpha_i r_i$ is maximized.

I would also be interested in an approximation algorithm or a heuristic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These authors try to minimize the number k of permutation matrices that are needed to decompose a specific DS matrix and show that this problem is NP-hard: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01270331v2/document